# "Username copied!" not showing for text.configure(text="Username copied!") before text.after(3000, ...)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want the "*Username copied!*" to display only for 3 seconds, after that, the string will change to "*Welcome back*".

But what's happening is, when I click the button, after 3 seconds, "*Welcome*" will change to "*Welcome back*" right away, the "*Username copied!*" doesn't show in between.

```
from tkinter import *
from urllib import parse
from tkinter import Tk

window = Tk()
window.title("CopyText")
window.geometry('295x70+600+210')

myFont = ('Verdana',11)

#USERNAME ===================

lbl = Label(window, text="Username:")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
string1 = StringVar(value='myusername')

txt = Entry(window, textvariable=string1, font=myFont, width=18)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)


def clicked():
    copy = txt.get()
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(copy)

    # after button was clicked, change "Welcome" to "Username copied!" 
    welcomeMessage.configure(text="Username copied!")          

    # then after 3 seconds, change the "Username copied!" to "Welcome back"        
    welcomeMessage.after(3000, welcomeMessage.configure(text="Welcome back"))  
    r.update()

btn = Button(window, text="copy", command=clicked, height=2, width=5)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

welcomeMessage = Label(window, text="Welcome")
welcomeMessage.grid(column=1, row=7)


window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: You are changing the text to "Welcome back" *right now*, and then 3 seconds later you are calling whatever `.configure()` returned (which is probably None).  You need to pass a function to `.after()`, not usually the result of calling a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this line:

```
welcomeMessage.after(3000, welcomeMessage.configure(text="Welcome back"))
```

It is functionally identical as this:

```
result = welcomeMessage.configure(text="Welcome back")
welcomeMessage.after(3000, result)
```

Since `result` is `None`, nothing happens after 3 seconds.

Arguably, the best solution is to create a proper function and call that from the `after` method:

```
def show_welcome():
    welcomeMessage.configure(text="Welcome back")
welcomeMessage.after(3000, show_welcome)
```

You can also solve this easily with `lambda` or `functools.partial`. Here's how you would do it with `lambda`:

```
welcomeMessage.after(3000, lambda: welcomeMessage.configure(text="Welcome back"))
```